# Browser Error when i run MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am getting an error on my browser when i try to edit or delete it says:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /console/Delete/PS3
```

But the strange thing is when i put my mouse cursor into the browser address bar and press enter the delete and edit page appears

Can you please help me with this. If you need any information regarding this just let me know and i will provide.

Comment: Do you go to this page from a link or a submitted form ?

Comment: I type into to the browser bar to get this page

Comment: do you have the relevant controller and action methods  ? what is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have added routing for "/".

In most cases it is because of omitted routes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because the related actions has [Get] attribute defined on them, so add [Post] attribute should solve the problem.

Comment: What about remove bothing [Get] and [Post]?

Comment: Nope no effect still the same error, to access the page I have to press enter in the browser address bar